# Does <br> correspond to LINE SEPARATOR (U+2028)?

Tags: html, unicode, line-breaks, bidi

Let say I have the following text (in typing order from left to right) where the line break is
U+2028 and capital letter represent arabic letter and everything else represent itself.

```
foo FOO
!BAR@
```

I put them in html like this,

```
<p dir="auto">foo FOO<br>!BAR@</p>
```

chromium and firefox both display them as,

```
foo OOF
!RAB@
```

Based on my understanding of Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm (and by also viewing
the plain text in text editor) the '!' and '@' should be displayed next to each
other. Like this,

```
foo OOF
RAB!@
```

Is this a bug in the browser or `<br>` does not actually correspond to U+2028? And
how to insert (or have the semantic of) U+2028?

Browsers only display blank horizontal space for `&#x2028;` (I put the spaces for quoting).

Comment: Have you checked with the WHATWG/W3 specification for the exact definition and semantics of `<br>`?

Comment: Please ignore the 'I put the spaces for quoting' at the end. I forgot to remove those words.

Comment: You may need to insert BIDI directional override characters to get the layout you want (bug or not).

Comment: @Dai I have not read much and I dont understand alot of html/css.

Comment: @Paul I can get what I want by using &rlm; but I wanted a solution without this.

Comment: Instead of using \<br> perhaps use separate \<p> elements (with appropriate styling to take care of spacing).

Comment: @Paul I do not want separate paragraphs, only line break exactly like U+2028.

Comment: I checked with the Current HTML LS, and `<br>`'s definition does not directly correspond to any particular Unicode code-points or characters, including `\r`, `\n`, nor `U+2028` - in fact, `U+2028` has coimplicated handling rules in HTML already that browsers (even today) handle inconsistently (see [UAX14](https://unicode.org/reports/tr14/)) - let alone combined with Unicode BIDI rules. As far as you're concerned, the answer is "no" - and to avoid presuming anything about U+2028 for now until browsers get their act together.

Answer (score -1):

The visually rendered output of this HTML...

```html
<p dir="auto"> foo FOO <br> !BAR@ </p>
```

will be

```
foo FOO
!BAR@
```

because `<br>` tag is used for line breaker

Comment: The OP's example had `RAB` and not `BAR` because they're using Bidi. Your answer does not consider that.